# logging inside a class or entity

Tags: logging, symfony

I'm trying to shift the error logging responsibility to my class/entity.
Currently the only clean way to get an instance of the logger is from my controller, only to then pass it on to my entity.

**Is there a clean way to get an instance of the logger inside my class or entity?**

Same goes for the Entitymanager

edit: setter injection:

- Test.php

[image]

- services.yml

  ```
  services:
      my_test:
          class: AppBundle\Entity\Test        
          arguments: ["@logger"]
          calls:
               - [setLogger, ["@logger"]]
  ```
- DefaultController.php

  ```
  $test = new Test();
  $test->doLog();
  ```

the error I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function error() on null

because it's didn't call the setter

Comment: You should not use the logger, the entity manager or any other service within you entity. For your custom service classes, you should read about dependency injection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: please see my edit above

Comment: Are you using the framework or just some of the components standalone?

Comment: the entire symfony framework, also the default monolog logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your class as a service you **must not** call the constructor yourself. The service container will care about constructing the object.

Instead you have to get your logger like this (assuming you want to get it within a controller):

```php
class MyController extends Controller {

    public function someAction() {
        // ...
        $test = $this->get('my_test');
        $test->doLog();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also the correct service definition for you would be:

```yaml
services:
    my_test:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\Test        
        calls:
             - [setLogger, ["@logger"]]
```

The `arguments` key is used to pass arguments to the constructor of the class. But you are using setter injection, so the arguments key is wrong here.